# how to fix Html divs moving when browser resized

Tags: html, css, layout, resize

Hi i am new to css and i got a problem in coding, I have 4 divs in my html page and i arranged them as two to the left and two to the right of the header. My problem is when i re-size the browser window my divs which are on the right of the header are moving downwards how can i fix this and how can i arange the div with equal distance to the header ..

here is the image of my site what it looks like http://postimg.org/image/pg1oay3wl/

Please find my html and css here             jsfiddle.net/hmz7g

Please help me in his issue.....

Thanks in anticipation of your help.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping multiple divs within a div will solve this problem.

E.g.

```
    <div id="wrapper">

   <div id="box1" class="left">
   </div>

   <div id="box2" class="left">
   </div>


   <div id="box3" class="right">
   </div>

   <div id="box4" class="right">
   </div>
```

you could make one 'wrapper' div with all the boxes inside, and make the 'class' for all the boxes float left or right using CSS.

E.g.

```
    #wrapper{

width:900px;
height:auto;
position:relative;

}

.left{

float:left;

}

.right{

float:right;

}

#box1{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position relative;
    background-color:#0F0;
}

#box2{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position relative;
    background-color:#00F;
}

#box3{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position relative;
    background-color:#C30;
}

#box4{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position relative;
    background-color:#90F;
}
```

I have colored each box differently and have positioned them how you described you wanted above. you can re-size/color them using my example to give you a better idea.

I hope this helps.